# How To Send Object in Form Data in React.js

Tags: reactjs, fetch, multipartform-data

Actually i am sending a Form Data Which contains input text and input Files I am doing it like This but i am getting an empty object in response

Here is my Code

```
  const [ModelInfo,setModelInfo] = useState({
            title:"",
            description:"",
            category:""
    })

 const [Modelfile,setModelfile] = useState({
           file1:"",
           file3:"",
           file4:""
    })
```

Here Is My Fuction To Handle Submit

```
    e.preventDefault();

    const formData = new FormData();

     // My Post Files Object 

     for(let key in Modelfile){
        formData.append(key,Modelfile[key][0])
     }

     // My Post Text Object 

     for(let key in ModelInfo){
        formData.append(key,ModelInfo[key])
     }


    fetch("http://192.168.10.8:8300/createpost",{
        method:"POST",
        body:formData
    })
    .then((resp)=>{        
        resp.json().then((data) => {
            console.log(data)
        })
    })
```

```
Payload :
file1: (binary)
file3: (binary)
file4: (binary)
title: test
description: test
category: test

Preview : {}

Getting Empty Obj in response
```

[ScreenShot 1 Of Post Request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EYu6Y.jpg)

[ScreenShot 2 Of Post Request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WvXRd.jpg)

Comment: Maybe there are some bugs in your backend.

Comment: Can you check your request body in the developer console to be sure you really have a frontend issue.

Comment: on Client Side it show me Empty `FormData {}` and server side i did nothing but just resp.send(req.body)

Comment: Please provide some more data so we can help you fix the bug. (Screenshot of your request in browser, backend code, etc)

Comment: Here is my server route for post request *****postRouter.post("/createpost", (req,resp) => {
    resp.send(req.body)
})

Comment: And Other Question I am new to Stack Over Flow So how can i send a ScreenShot in Comment is there any way

Comment: Just edit your question. No need to send them in the comments section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some possibilities that may cause the issue:

1. Your headers are not set properly. Set Content-Type header to multipart/form-data or application/x-www-form-urlencoded when sending your data.
2. On your server, you don't have [body-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser) or [multer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer#readme) library. You should use this libraries (not together) in order to access your req.body and parse it.
3. Maybe you forgot to add this config (in your index file in the root directory of the server):

```js
app.use(express.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}))
```

As a note, you can access your files with req.files in server and other fields with req.body.

Answer (score 0):

If You did n't add a multer library to your server side then the form data will return an empty object because multer add a body object and a file object to requested object so use a multer library but dont forget to add enctype="multipart/formdata" to you form body .

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).